# How to Stop PS6 Vanishing Point Tool Pixelating Images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, mockup

I've always run into this issue, and diving into it a bit more today, I can't seem to figure out 'HOW' to stop the PS6 vanishing tool from pixelating my website mock-ups!

I often mock-up web screenshots on devices for my portfolio and clients.  (Perspective monitors, smartphone devices etc.) and I typically use the vanishing tool to do so.  Problem is, the vanishing tool forces me to rasterize my image before its able to be placed on the grid, rather then allowing me to transform the vector versions of it.  This results in a lot of jagged edges and major quality loss on type.

My question is: is there a way to use the vanishing point tool with vector (or grouped) objects?  If not, is there a better way for me to make these transforms for my mock-ups?  Using the skew / transform tool proves to be time consuming and inconsistent.

Comment: It shouldn't pixelate things anymore than the background image is pixelated.

Answer (score 1):

A) Do it in Illustrator

B) make your mock up base images larger, then rasterize and you should have no jaggies.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeff G - @rangi has the right idea. If you can create it within Illustrator then that would help. If it has to be Photoshop, then a larger file size, either by pixel dimensions and/or change the DPI which in turn does the same thing. The larger the files the better it will hold up. At the end of the day, if the original is small then there's not much you can do. As they say, "crap in, crap out".

Answer (score 0):

1.Ctl+T with layer selected

2.Right Click Layer - Select Distort

3.Drag points to corners of you devices etc.

Comment: Hey Javi, thanks for your reply, but this doesn't quite do the trick.  This only works with raster objects, and I'm looking for a vector solution.

Comment: Have you tried converting the vector into a smart object. It may say its a smart object, however if right click the layer and convert into smart object again, you will then be able to use the above steps.This will still preserve your vector within another smart object.